# how to automatically add a schedule from Google Sheets into Calendar without create a duplicate event? Is there a way to run daily automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

This part works... now i need automate and create only new records add in the spreadsheet. Please, i need a help!

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CJ3").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CI5:CK3500").getValues();
  for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
    var endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
    var volunteer= shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer,startTime,endTime);
    Utilities.sleep(300)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate your sheets? Could you please provide a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, for example, in order to check the duplicated event, how about using a status column? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function scheduleShifts() {
  var statusColumn = "CL"; // As a sample, this script uses the column "CL".
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CJ3").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CI5:CL3500").getValues();
  var rangeList = [];
  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    if (shift[3] == "done") continue;
    rangeList.push(statusColumn + (x + 5));
    var startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
    var endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
    var volunteer = shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
    Utilities.sleep(300)
  }
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue("done");
}
```

- This script uses the column "CL" as the status column. When this script is run, when the colum "CL" has no value of "done", the event is created and put the value of "done" to the column "CL". When the script is run again, the rows which have the value of "done" at the column "CL" are skipped. By this, the duplicated events are not created.

#### Note:

- This script uses the column "CL" as the status column. When you want to put this for other column, please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: @NEEMIAS Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: HI! I have the same issue. The script create a duplicate events again. Is this right  "if (shift[3] == "done") continue;"?

Comment: @NEEMIAS About your new question of `HI! I have the same issue. The script create a duplicate events again. Is this right "if (shift[3] == "done") continue;"?`, in my proposed script, `shift[3]` is the column "CL". When the value of "done" is not existing in the column "CL", the script for creating the event is run. So, please check the column "CL" again.

Comment: shouldn't the code write "done" in the CL column for every event created in the schedule? After running the script, the CL column remains unchanged, that is, without "done"... So, the next time the code is executed, the same event is created...

Comment: I think the code needs record "done" in the CL spreadsheet column after create a new evento to not create a duplicate event next time script runs...

Comment: Column CL in my spreadsheet is blank after script runs...

Comment: I think i know what is happening... i will try to specific the spreadsheet like that: var statusColumn = "Dados!CL";

Comment: @NEEMIAS Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. In order to correctly understand your reply, can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: There are nothing to apologize... your solution works, but after run the script, the rows/records in my spreadsheet and column (Dados!CL) does not changed to "done". So, when script runs again, a duplicate event is created.

Comment: i dont know what is wrong...

Comment: @NEEMIAS Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because when I tested my proposed script, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Tanaike, here are the link to a "copy" of the spreeadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLbI6WcyfgOHqct1dfIrt7l7Zlrpa6_jvW8H1TB7-hE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NEEMIAS Thank you for replying. When I tested my script to your provided Spreadsheet, although, unfortunately, the values of "CI5:CI9" is `#REF!`, `done` is put to the cells "CL5:CL9". Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `your solution works, but after run the script, the rows/records in my spreadsheet and column (Dados!CL) does not changed to "done".`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly understand it, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.